# How can I call old objects from an Array?

Tags: android, arrays

I am storing my dynamic data in a dynamic String Array (HoleScore) inside an Activity that is a Scoreboard and can be minimized and opened every time. However, when I come back to this Activity from another one I just can't access the first object that I had stored before.

e.g.

If I come from hole_counter = 1, then I CAN see HoleScore[1];

If I come from hole_counter = 2, then I CAN NOT see the HoleScore[1], I just can see the HoleScore[2];

Which means that the First `// Printing data of Each Hole -- !!!!!` DOES NOT Print anything if I come from hole_counter = 2.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.plusgolf;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScoreBoard extends Activity 
{
    TextView hole_score, hole_score2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.scoreboard);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Picking Data from OnCourse
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        // Get Stroke & Par Number from OnCourse
        int stroke = extras.getInt("stroke");
        int par_number = extras.getInt("par_number");

        // Calling Core
        final Core calling_core = (Core) getApplicationContext();
        // Get hole_counter from Core
        final int hole_counter = calling_core.getHoleCounter();
        // Get Holes from Core (Total Holes of the Game)
        final int holes = calling_core.getHoles();

        // Creating Array of String to Store Data of Each Hole
        String[] HoleScore = new String[holes];

        // Storing Hole Data in Array
        HoleScore[hole_counter] = "Hole "+ hole_counter + " = " + stroke + " / " + par_number;

        // Printing Data of each Hole -- !!!!!
        hole_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hole_number1);
        hole_score.setText(HoleScore[1]);

        // Printing Data of each Hole
        hole_score2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hole_number2);
        hole_score2.setText(HoleScore[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're only setting HoleScore[hole_counter] for a single data point and not all of them...  HoleScore[hole_counter] = "Hole "+ hole_counter + " = " + stroke + " / " + par_number;

Comment: @AdiInbar Should I create an array for each variable like: hole_counter, stroke and par_number ?

Comment: I think you meant to address that to @Guardanis. I edited the post from the First Posts review queue; Android/Java is not my area of expertise.

Comment: @Guardanis Should I create an array for each variable like: hole_counter, stroke and par_number ?

Comment: No, you only need one array, but you're not populating it with all the values. You're only populating it with the selected one instead of all of them like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a better way to store these data that pass trough activities: Shared Preferences.
Much Better than send Bundles every time that I open the Second Activity.

So really I recommend using **Shared Preferences** for pass data that you will use more than 1 time trough activities.

FirstActivity:

```
// Starting Shared Preferences
public static String filename = "MySharedData";
SharedPreferences mySharedData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
// Editor
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedData.edit();
// Values to Send
editor.putInt("hole_" + hole_counter + "_stroke", stroke_counter);
editor.putInt("hole_"  + hole_counter + "_par" , par_number);
// Done Signal
editor.commit();
```

Second Activity:

```
// Starting Shared Preferences
public static String filename = "MySharedData";
SharedPreferences mySharedData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

// Getting All Data Stored from First Activity
for (int i = 0; i <= length.that.you.need; i++)
{
    strokeArray[i] = mySharedData.getInt("hole_" + i + "_stroke", 0);
    parArray[i] = mySharedData.getInt("hole_" + i + "_par", 0);
}
```

PS: The values os the variable hole_counter are Integers like "i" in the Second Activity and I use it to identify each Item that has its own *stroke* and *par* data.